# A leading 0 bug in dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

It seems that a leading 0 in a number causes error in dataframes. Can anybody replicate?

```
In [45]: df = pd.DataFrame({'hhmm': [930,1000,1300]})
In [46]: df = pd.DataFrame({'hhmm': [0930,1000,1300]})
  File "<ipython-input-46-3a3038c84b16>", line 1
    df = pd.DataFrame({'hhmm': [0930,1000,1300]})
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
In [47]:
```

Comment: umm not sure this is relevant, but leading zero typically means it's an octal literal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A leading zero causes a number to be interpreted as octal. `9` is not a valid octal digit, hence the error.

Note that [in Python 3, octal literals (numbers with leading 0s) are flat-out disallowed](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals) to avoid confusion with bases and such. Instead, `0o` must be used instead for octal literals.

Comment: Actually IIRC python does not support octals, to avoid this kind of errors.

Comment: A leading zero causes a number to be interpreted as octal for `2.x`, For `3.x`, its just a error.. right?